# Unexpected nohup behaviour

Tags: unix, posix, nohup

I have an executable file `test`, it contains

```
a="$RANDOM"
echo "$a">>out
```

Now, if I simply `./test` then `out` contains a random number. But if I `nohup ./test &` then out is empty. Why?

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu?  Is `/bin/sh` a link to `/bin/dash` rather than `/bin/bash`?  If so, when you run it with `bash` as your shell, then `$RANDOM` works, but when `nohup` runs it with `/bin/sh` (aka `dash`), you get nothing?  And you might be able to fix it by using `#!/bin/bash` as the shebang line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler actually I'm on Debian. But anyway I forgot the shebang indeed, now it works perfectly. Post an answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comment into an answer*</sup>

Are you on Ubuntu (or another Linux distro)? Is `/bin/sh` a link to `/bin/dash` rather than `/bin/bash`? If so, when you run it with `bash` as your shell, then `$RANDOM` works, but when `nohup` runs it with `/bin/sh` (aka `dash`), you get nothing.

You might be able to fix it by using `#!/bin/bash` as the shebang line.

> Actually I'm on Debian. But anyway I forgot the shebang indeed; now it works perfectly.

Great!

Incidentally, however tempting it is, it's generally a bad idea to call programs `test` because there is a shell built-in called `test` (also known as `[`) that can readily cause confusion if it is run instead of your test program.

Comment: The problem with test programs named `test` can be avoided by (a) *never* putting `.` into your `$PATH`, especially not at the beginning, and (b) cultivating the habit of running programs in the current directory by typing `./name`. Nevertheless, avoiding the name `test` can't hurt. On the other hand, there are a lot of other standard command names that you can easily collide with.

Comment: It wasn't really `test`, I just called it like this in the question. But it's good to know anyway, thanks!